# K-1-P (or Equivalent) from Multiple States

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, schedule-k-1

In 2012 and 2013, I worked for a company (LLC) that awarded me shares in the company as a form of compensation (*edit: the shares were issued in early 2013*).  I have since left the company and they bought back the shares.

I had been waiting to complete my 2013 taxes until I received the K-1 from this company.  I received the K-1 yesterday, and in addition to the K-1 for federal and for Illinois, I also received K-1 "equivalents" from two other states (California and Florida).

Does this mean I need to file returns with each state for which I got a K-1 equivalent?

Can software packages like TurboTax and TaxAct handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Was the company operating in California and Florida as well?

Comment: Did you not have to handle this for 2012 taxes?  Do you know the taxable year of the LLC?

Comment: @NL7: What I said is technically correct, but terribly misleading.  The equity was issued in 2013, not long before I left the company.  I'll clarify.

Comment: Yes, they had offices in Florida and California.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received K-1 for the States in which the LLC was operating and had income from. You should check if your personal income from these states (income reported to you on the K-1s) puts you above the filing threshold in these states - if so then yes, you should file a tax return there. You would probably be filing non-resident tax return only for the income sourced in these states.

LLC is a pass-through entity that doesn't pay its own taxes (except for California, but its a different tax and you have double taxation there), you as a partner have the burden of paying the taxes on the portion of income attributed to you.

I don't know whether tax packages handle this situation *well*, but I generally have good experience with TurboTax. All of them definitely support K-1s and income sourced to a particular state.

Comment: Good point about the threshold--probably don't need to file in the additional states, as the amount is small.  I decided to file an extension and have a tax professional do my taxes, as I didn't feel comfortable enough with answering TurboTax's questions.  Thanks for your answer.